# How to split column in Power Query by the first space?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using Power Query and have a column called LandArea; example data is "123.5 sq mi". It is of data type text. I want to remove the "sq mi" part so I just have the number value, 123.5. I tried the Replace function to replace "sq mi" with blank but that doesn't work because it looks at the entire text. So I tried to use Split where I split it on the space and it generated this formula below, and it did create a new column, but with null for all values. The original column still had "123.5 sq mi".

```
Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns1","LandArea",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),{"LandArea.1", "LandArea.2"})
```

When just splitting at the left-most delimiter:

```
Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns1","LandArea",Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.None, false),{"LandArea.1", "LandArea.2"})
```

I have also tried changing to QuoteStyle.Csv.  Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to create a custom column:

```
= Table.AddColumn(
  #"Reordered Columns1",
  "NewColumn",
  each Text.Start([LandArea],Text.PositionOf([LandArea]," "))
)
```

**UPDATE:** *Every one appears to have "sq mi"*

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Replace([LandArea]," sq mi",""),type number)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did not work. I also tried changing it to use Text.Range instead. It creates a new column with "Error" in it. I am still trying to figure out the right formula for adding a new column, but also still feel like Split should work?

Comment: @Kelly, What is the error you get? Do all your values have at least one white space?

Comment: good question, they do all have whitespace. Every one appears to have "sq mi" in it, there are no nulls or blanks in the original data.

Comment: Error: Expression.Error: The 'count' argument is out of range.
Details:
    -1

Comment: so I changed the formula to hardcode the Text.PositionOf result to 5 and it gave me values. So somewhere in there it's calculating a value that is out of range for Text.PositionOf...

Comment: yes that works! That's a good workaround, I will accept this as answer although a little bummed I couldn't get Split to work

Comment: also you can use "sq mi" in place of the " " when using PositionOf in your original answer.  I wonder if I have a strange whitespace character in there, like it's a non-breaking space instead of regular space or something. I copied these values off of a website into Excel first

Comment: @Kelly, a bit odd. About the Split function I think text manipulation is faster in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns1", "LandArea2", 
    each Text.Start([LandArea], Text.PositionOf([LandArea], "sq")-1))
```

I avoided trying to find whitespace.

Comment: Position of can be configured to return only one match, like ` = Text.PositionOf( text, substring, Occurrence.First )`    -- `Occurrence.Last` is useful as well